# In "The Big O", who was real?

Tags: the-big-o

In *The Big O*, we find out that Angel has been behind the whole “show” that is Roger Smith’s life.

The question begs: was *anyone* real aside from Angel? Or did she have control over people’s minds? Or was it *literally* a giant set under her control?

I’ve always been intrigued by this concept from that show along with its black noire style.